# Where can I see source code for java or python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm studying programming language such as Java and Python. and now

I want to know how people make coding for large scale project to study further.

Is there a site where I can see source code or project for Java and Python?

Comment: For python, after installation, you can go to python directory(`...\python35\Lib\.`) and look inside `.py` files.

Answer (score 0):

For learning and understanding an unknown code base, it is always a good idea to start with the documentation.

For python you can find a good "Getting started" Guide here: https://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html

However, keep in mind that it you will need plenty of time to understand large codebases like python. This is definitely nothing you can learn in one afternoon.

Nevertheless, if you are really interested in contributing to open source projects it could be worth it.